# iOS Disk access based restore function

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, data-recovery

I am trying to code a hard disk based restore function into an existing demo Photo Application for iOS devices. The idea is to allow users to restore the last applied effects and all, even after restarting the application/unexpected crash etc.

I am saving one image file (the latest effects applied to it) into the NSCachesDirectory:

```
     NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:[self getFileAtIndex:getPath] atomically:YES];
```

On going to the recover option, the file saved at this path is recovered using:

```
    image = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self getFileAtIndex:getPath]]retain];
```

The code is working fine in my test device (iPhone 4s). But somehow I doubt if this is the best practice for coding a restore function.

Moving into a real world app, if things were stored in NSCachesDirectory, do you think it will be backed up into iCloud? Is there any possibility of a conflict with other apps?

How exactly is NSCachesDirectory directory managed for multiple apps accessing it simultaneously?

I would like to know the best practice for doing this.

Please help/comment.

Comment: NSCachesDirectory is not backed up into cloud. Only files into NSDocumentDirectoty. No possible conflict since all apps have their own NSCachesDirectory / NSDocumentDirectoty etc..

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. Bonjour mentioned in the comment, on iOS, every app has its separate file system, so there can never be any conflict with other apps.

Caches directory is not backed up on iCloud and you shouldn't rely on files in caches directory to persist across launches. You should use caches directory for temporary files only. If you allow restore only during one session, then using caches directory is fine, but if you want to allow restore across multiple launches, you should store them in library/documents directory. But be aware that Apple has a strict review policy for storing files in Documents directory since it takes up space on user's cloud storage.

Comment: But if I use NSDocumentDirectory, the back up file will find itself in iCloud - not desirable. Not sure about the policy regarding NSLibraryDirectory. Will read up on this.

Comment: If you want backup: use documents.
If you want file accessible across launches: use Library.
If you want file accessible only in this session: use Caches.

Comment: Ok... got it. One more question... if I'm using Caches and I fail to delete my temporary files, will it be auto purged when memory is constrained? Or am I the one responsible for managing it and failure to comply will result in rejection from Apple?

Comment: Given the nature of caches directory, I think it's safe to assume you can let it be and iOS will purge it as and when required, but I personally don't have experience with what Apple reviewer's think of it.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'll put this into my app and see... thanks a lot for all the help.